# Fluids: What is the relationship between discharge coefficient and external tube length?

Tags: fluid-mechanics

Read this [article](http://www.codecogs.com/library/engineering/fluid_mechanics/pipes/mouthpiece/external-mouthpiece.php).

Summary: The article claims the **coefficient of discharge** decreases with increase in **length**, "due to greater frictional resistance between the walls of the mouthpiece and the flowing water."

Edit: Verified this experimentally (albeit with vertical set-up)
[image: Experimental set-up]

The losses due to friction increase with pipe length. Reducing the coefficient of discharge very slightly.

Comment: 'read this article'... besides it sounding overbearing, it is best to give a small summary of the article or quote its important parts. If the link is ever broken, the question can stand on itself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the function of the mouthpiece is to allow the flow to fully develop again. Assuming the length is exactly enough for the flow to be fully developed, then increasing the length will have no impact on the flow and thus the discharge coefficient. Shortening the mouth piece will result in a underdeveloped flow and the discharge coefficient will change, with the limiting value being the case where no mouthpiece is used.